# How to delete particular letter from different words in VI

Tags: linux, unix, vim, vi

For example, I have text like, " ram shyam hari gita nita "  and here  I suppose to delete letter "a" from each word, I'm seeking command to delete whole "a" from each word.

Comment: Does `:%s/a//g` do what you want?

Comment: thanks mate , it works :)

Comment: @jww: Perhaps [Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to recommend. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command:

```
:%s/a//g
```

it will delete all of the `a`s in the buffer.